# How to build a trigger for 2 scenarios in 1 object which will create/update multiple records in another unrelated object?

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

**Scenario 1:**

a) Trigger on Custom Object 'Prod' only when record type = 'Forecast'.

b) It should take data from 1 custom **date** field and 3 custom **number** fields in Object 'Prod'

c) Then creates 3 records in Custom Object 'Inv' - Each record will have that 1 date field and 1 of the custom **number** field from 'Prod'

***Scenario 2:***

a) Trigger on Custom Object 'Prod' only when record type = 'Actual'

b) It should take data from the same custom **date** field and 3 different custom **number** fields in Object 'Prod'

c) Result of this will update the 3 records in 'Inv' with the respective correct date and volume

Here is my Apex Trigger:

```
trigger ProductionTrigger on Prod__c (before insert, before update) {

List<Prod__c> prod_Forecast = new List<Prod__c>();
List<Prod__c> prod_Actual = new List<Prod__c>();
List<Inv__c> inv_Forecast = new List<Inv__c>();
List<Inv__c> inv_afterInsertForecast = new List<Inv__c>();
List<Inv__c> inv_toUpdateWithActuals = new List<Inv__c>();

for (Prod__c p : Trigger.new) {
    //Loop through all records in the Trigger.new collection only if Production = 'Forecast'
    if (p.RecordTypeId == Schema.SObjectType.Prod__c.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('Forecast').RecordTypeId) {
        prod_Forecast.add(p);

    } else if (p.RecordTypeId == Schema.SObjectType.Prod__c.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('Actual').RecordTypeId) {
            prod_Actual.add(p);

    }
}

//Only trigger for when record type = 'Forecast'
if (prod_Forecast.isEmpty() == false) {
    for (Prod__c p : prod_Forecast){
        if (p.A_Volume__c != 0){
            Inv__c inv = new Inv__c();
            inv.Inventory_Date__c = p.Production_Date__c;
            inv.Product_Family__c = 'Liquid A';
            inv.Product_Grade__c = 'A';
            inv.Incoming_Stock__c = p.A_Volume__c;
            inv_Forecast.add(inv);
        }
        if (p.B_Volume__c != 0) {
            Inv__c inv2 = new Inv__c();
            inv2.Inventory_Date__c = p.Production_Date__c;
            inv2.Product_Family__c = 'Liquid B';
            inv2.Product_Grade__c = 'B';
            inv2.Incoming_Stock__c = p.B_Volume__c;
            inv_Forecast.add(inv2);
        }
        if (p.C_Volume__c != 0) {
            Inv__c inv3 = new Inv__c();
            inv3.Inventory_Date__c = p.Production_Date__c;
            inv3.Product_Family__c = 'Liquid C';
            inv3.Product_Grade__c = 'C';
            inv3.Incoming_Stock__c = p.C_Volume__c;
            inv_Forecast.add(inv3);
        } 
    }
    if (inv_Forecast.size() > 0) {
        insert inv_Forecast;

        inv_afterInsertForecast = ([SELECT Id, Inventory_Date__c , Product_Family__c, Product_Grade__c, Opening_Stock__c
                            FROM Inv__c
                            WHERE id IN :inv_Forecast]);
    }
}   

//Only trigger for when record type = 'Actual'
if (prod_Actual.isEmpty() == false) {
    for (Prod__c p : prod_Actual){
        for (Inv__c i : inv_afterInsertForecast){
            if (i.Inventory_Date__c == p.Production_Date__c &&
                i.Product_Family__c == 'Liquid A' &&
                i.Product_Grade__c == 'A' ){
                    Inv__c invA = new Inv__c();
                    invA.id = i.id;
                    invA.Inventory_Volume__c = p.A_Volume__c;
                    inv_toUpdateWithActuals.add(invA);
                }
            if (i.Inventory_Date__c == p.Production_Date__c &&
                i.Product_Family__c == 'Liquid B' &&
                i.Product_Grade__c == 'B'){
                    Inv__c invB = new Inv__c();
                    invB.id = i.id;
                    invB.Inventory_Volume__c = p.B_Volume__c;
                    inv_toUpdateWithActuals.add(invB);
                }
            if (i.Inventory_Date__c == p.Production_Date__c &&
                i.Product_Family__c == 'Liquid C' &&
                i.Product_Grade__c == 'C'){
                    Inv__c invC = new Inv__c();
                    invC.id = i.id;
                    invC.Inventory_Volume__c = p.B_Volume__c;
                    inv_toUpdateWithActuals.add(invC);
                }
        }
    }
    if (inv_toUpdateWithActuals.size() > 0) {
        update inv_toUpdateWithActuals;
    }
}
```

}

**Unexpected outcomes from my code**

- It can accomplish Scenario 1 by creating 3 records in Inv__c but somehow also creates records in Prod__c for ALL Prod__c record types.
- It doesn't update the 3 records in inventory at all even when I mapped the **Inventory_Date__c**, Product_family__c and Product_group__c.

Help please?

****UPDATE****
Also a few side questions (besides the fact I need to make handlers to minimize the codebase in triggers) :

1) Are my parameters correct that I did before insert, before update on the 1st line of my code? (was thinking scenario 2 would be after insert, after update)

2) How could I have done this differently using Map, Set?

3) I tried to separate both scenarios using Trigger.IsBefore/ Trigger.isUpdate/ Trigger.isInsert but had an inkling that separating by record types should be good enough

Comment: For your point 2, I notice `Inv__c` creation uses a field `Inventory_Date__c `, but your update uses `Plan_Date__c `. Is the latter derived from the former? I don't completely follow your point 1 about creating for all record types - aren't you creating `Inv__c` records, not `Prod__c`?

Comment: oh crap good catch yeah all should be ‘inventory_date__c’. Trigger happens when I insert a record in Prod__c. It somehow inserts records in Prod_c for all record types instead of just for ‘forecast’.

Comment: I'll add an answer if that turns out to be helpful, but it sounds like you had another issue, right? With creating the wrong records? Could you elaborate on that one a little?

Comment: You should really learn about handler and service patterns. Putting all your code in the trigger body is bad practice, does not enforce sharing rules, and makes your code quite difficult to test, especially in any sort of modular fashion.

Comment: @DavidReed yeah updated the question. 2 issues. [1] when I input the 4 custom fields in Scenario 1 and save, it somehow creates a record for each of the record types in Prod__c. [2] for Scenario 2 I can't get it to update my 3 newly created records in Inv__c

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeap I know. But I was just trying to do a proof of concept first if this could be done. Very few example guides out there (as compared to Java) on the best practice of how to organize apex triggers and apex classes so I did the best I could for now...

Comment: Your code doesn't do any DML on `Prod__c` objects, only `Inv__c` records. If you have extra copies of `Prod__c` objects, the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot to tackle here. I'm going to try to give a pretty broad treatment of the separate issues here and I hope that the refactoring that addressing these issues will involve will both add clarity and serendipitously resolve other problems you're seeing.

#### Scenario 1 / Issue 1

Your code appears to be to be correct for Scenario 1, *save* that it's implemented in the trigger body rather than inspecting the trigger operation (either using `Trigger.isInsert` and friends or looking at `Trigger.operationType`). More on the issues this causes below.

The issue you're seeing with multiple `Prod__c` objects of different record types being inserted appears to have nothing to do with this trigger *per se*.

#### Scenario 2 / Issue 2

This issue has a lot to do with the structure of the trigger. Let me pull out a skeleton here and try to show why that's the case.

```
trigger ProductionTrigger on Prod__c (before insert, before update) {
    for (Prod__c p : Trigger.new) {
        // Accumulate records in collections
    }

    if (prod_Forecast.isEmpty() == false) {
        // Create Inv__c records.
    }
    if (inv_Forecast.size() > 0) {
        // Insert and requery Inv__c records.
        // NOTE that this code will *only* execute when there exist `Forecast`
        // records in the trigger set. Otherwise `inv_afterInsertForecast` will be empty.
        // If there is a mixture of `Forecast` and `Actual` records,
        // we only requery the new `Forecast`-related Inv__c records.
        // Also, what happens if you update `Forecast` records without
        // changing their record types? There's an issue.
        insert inv_Forecast;

        inv_afterInsertForecast = ([SELECT Id, Inventory_Date__c , Product_Family__c, Product_Grade__c, Opening_Stock__c
                            FROM Inv__c
                            WHERE id IN :inv_Forecast]);
    }

    if (prod_Actual.isEmpty() == false) {
        for (Prod__c p : prod_Actual){
            // Iterate over `inv_afterInsertForecast`
            // Match records and update them
        }
        if (inv_toUpdateWithActuals.size() > 0) {
            update inv_toUpdateWithActuals;
        }
    }
}
```

So trace the execution path here if you're changing `Prod__c` records from `Forecast` to `Actual`. The trigger's going to execute in `before update` context, but not `before insert`. You'll collect `Actual` records, but not `Forecast`s (we're supposing a homogenous group).

So no `Inv__c` records get created, and `inv_afterInsertForecast` is *empty*.

We get down to your `if (prod_Actual.isEmpty() == false)` loop and enter the `if`. Then, the `for` looks at that empty collection `inv_afterInsertForecast` and... does nothing.

You'll never get those `Inv__c` records updated because you never query them in `before update` context. The code that runs on insert hasn't happened.

#### Issue 3

> Are my parameters correct that I did before insert, before update on the 1st line of my code? (was thinking scenario 2 would be after insert, after update)

It doesn't appear to me to make a difference in these scenarios, since you're not using the `Id` of the `Prod__c` object and you're not performing any updates against `Prod__c` itself. If you were using the `Id`, you'd need `after insert`.

#### Issue 4

> How could I have done this differently using Map, Set?

I would refactor this trigger first before worrying about this question. You'll find that you likely need a Map in your `before update` scenario - you'll query your `Inv__c` records, and then you'll want to postprocess them into a `Map<String, Inv__c`, where your keys will be a concatenation of the three parameters you use to uniquely identify the `Inv__c` records you want for any given `Prod__c`. That will let you pull them with a `Map.get()` rather than a combinatorial search (visit every `Inv__c` for every `Prod__c`), which is slow.

> I tried to separate both scenarios using Trigger.IsBefore/ Trigger.isUpdate/ Trigger.isInsert but had an inkling that separating by record types should be good enough

You need to implement a trigger handler class with separate methods for each trigger event due to issues like the above. You'll find it'll also make your code a lot easier to understand - getting confused about which code executes in which context is one of the major flaws of putting everything into the trigger body.

Comment: Wow thank alot for the in-depth answer! Yeah by inserting debug logs everywhere, I noticed it never entered the double for loop. Never knew some trigger like this took into account so many things. I really liked your Map<String, Inv__c> approach .. thought the only way was Map<Id,Inv__c>

Comment: Btw in reply to Issue 2. I'm only assuming the user will insert a Forecast record once (creating 3 inventory records). And then later on insert a Actual record once (updating 3 inventory records). Since they are both insert functions that's where it leads to my struggle on issue 4  as not sure how to separate them trigger wise

Comment: Well, if everything is happening upon insert, you don't need `before update`. You do, however, need logic that can handle records being inserted in separate transactions, as well as mixed transactions.

Comment: The process builders were the one causing the weird behaviours and the map via string concats really helped.